# iOS Universal Links not working via TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I'm new to iOS and managed to implement the iOS Universal Links for an app following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html?utm_source=revxblog).

I have created and uploaded the **apple-app-site-association** and configured/prepared the app  to handle universal links.

It all works well and I can test it successfully when I build the app through xCode into a real device. However the universal links do not work when installing the app via TestFlight.

When installing the app via xCode I can see the HTTP request to the apple-app-site-association file in my web server. But when installing it via TestFlight doesn't seem to try to fetch the association file.

Does anyone knows if this is expected or how can get universal links working when deploying on TestFlight?

Comment: what value did you set for "path" in apple-app-site-association file?

Comment: Hi @GemaMegantara, I set it to:  "paths": ["*"]

Comment: try adding "/" to the path, so it looks like this: `"paths": ["*", "/"]`, and re-install the app after changing the path, then test again.

Comment: thanks @GemaMegantara, made the change but didn't make any difference. works when building on xCode but still not working via TestFlight

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Have you try the app with adhoc distribution using such as diawi? If on the adhoc is working, I think it's safe to saying that it'll work on the App Store version later.

Comment: connect your device with mac and see device log, it's may contain useful information.

Comment: Thanks GemaMegantara will try diawi and see what happens.  Hi @SPatel when connecting the device it works fine, problem is only when app is installed via TestFlight

Comment: Have the same issue. Was it resolved?

Comment: Have the same issue still. Any leads on the fix?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure your Associated Domains are in both entitlement files: "Debug" and "Release". 
In my case all domains were listed in Entitlement-Debug.plist file but the Entitlement-Release.plist was empty.

After adding them manually to the 'Release' file - app installed via TestFlight started working with Universal Links.

Answer (score 0):

Distribution via Testflight will also not work, if you have protected test-Environments and use ?mode=developer to bypass Apple's CDN. Developer mode is only taken into account if the App is signed with a development profile.

Reference here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The fix was to use the same BRANCH_KEY for both Debug and Release mode.