# Apple-app-site-association file not linking to application

Tags: ios, swift, apple-app-site-associate

Even after 48 hours, as said in apple documentation, apple-app-site-association is not working in my application. I have checked with [apple validation tools] (https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/) but its showing Error no apps associated with url in the Link to Application. Here is the format of my apple-app-site-association file

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "{team_id}.{bundle_id}",
            "paths": ["*"]
        }]
    }
}
```

I have also enabled Associated Domains for the appId from developer.apple.com and in the XCode capabilities settings also.

I have already tried [this] ([iOS Universal Links not working via TestFlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093464/ios-universal-links-not-working-via-testflight))

Also check the [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106816) but couldn't find a solution there also.

Comment: Can you paste a link that is supposed to work on a note on Notes app and try to long press it. If everything is ok you should see a "Open with" entry for your app. It happens to me that the only way to get it to work is by downloading the app from app store directly, neither xcode release or testflight one seems to work.

Comment: I have done recently. let me find issue

Comment: @tx2 I've done your suggest step even I've tried with ```openurl booted 'https://{mydomain_here}/``` as suggested in some post. 
This command launches the app on simulator but still is not working in device

Comment: @KapilSharma give me your site link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are following these steps

1. Enabled Associated Domains in the app App services from the developer.apple.com
2. Set the domain name correctly in the Associated Domains in the Xcode capabilities and also enabled this.
3. You have correctly generated the apple-app-site-association file. The file must not have any extension. Here is the format for the file:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": “{app_prefix}.{your_app_bundle_identifier}”,
            "paths": ["*"]
        }]
    }
}
```

Make sure apps tag in the file is be empty and appID is made up of your app Prefix and bundle identifier separated by.

NOTE: I don't know why but I am using app prefix instead teamID as mentioned in most of the posts and even on the apple documentation. But it didn't work for me.

You can also try by using app prefix of the app id instead of teamID

Comment: I just replace my team_id with app_prefix and its started working.
Seems weird as team_id was mentioned in apple documentation BUT working with app_prefix

Comment: what's the the difference between team_id and app_prefix? isn't app prefix always team id??

Answer (score 5):

Little late to this thread but if you want Apple to call your app-site-association file each time the app is installed, simply do this:

```
applinks:[domain]?mode=developer
```

This way you can change the settings of the file while developing!